# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str' with a datetime module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to make a simple age calculator using datetime module and the users input. Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
    if day == now.day and month == now.month:
         age = now.year - year
    if day != now.day or  month != now.month:
         age  = now.year - age - 1
    if now.year - year  == -1:
        print("Be serious, please.")
    if now.year - rok < -1:
        print("Be serious,please.")
    print(age)
```

It gives me the following error: age = now.year - rok - 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
    And when I replace now.day and now.month and now.year with variables I assigned to them, it also gives me this error, the only difference is, that instead of now.year, it displays current_year.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
today = now.day 
current_month = now.month 
current_year = now.year
if day == now.day and month == now.month:
          age = current_year - year
if day != now.day or  month != now.month:
    age  = current_year - age - 1
if current_year - year  == -1:
    print("Be serious, please.")
if now.year - rok < -1:
    print("Be serious,please.")
print(age)
```

Comment: You don't define `day`,`month`,`year` or `rok` in the code provided and `age` is poorly defined. Ensure that these items are a) defined properly and b) that they are of type `int`

Comment: All you need is not to mix data types together. Can not compare, for example, the integer 5 with the string "5" because it is equal to fail. What type of data is the `rok` ? Is this an integer type ? I can not see its definition in your code anywhere.

Comment: Oh. Rok was meant to be year, this mistake occured, when I was translating variables names to English.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code to help you with your issue:

```
import datetime
polling = True
while polling:
   print("Please enter your birthday with this format(year, month, day)")
   user_year = int(input('Which year were you born in?: '))
   user_month = int(input('Which month were you born in?: '))
   user_day = int(input("which day of the month were you born on?: "))
   birthday = datetime.datetime(user_year, user_month, user_day)
   now = datetime.datetime.now()

   if user_day == now.day and month == now.month:
      age = now.year - birthday.year

   elif user_day != now.day or user_month != now.month and now.hour - birthday.hour > 24:
      age = (now.year - birthday.year) - 1

   elif user_day != now.day or user_month != now.month and now.hour - birthday.hour < 24:
    age = now.year - birthday.year

   if age <= 0:
     print('Be serious man')
     print('Enter your real age')
     continue

   else:
     print('You age is: {}'.format(age))

     prompt = input("Would you like to allow someone else to enter their age?(yes/no): ")
     if prompt.lower == 'no':
        polling = False
```

Here is an example of the output:

```
Please enter your birthday with this format(year, month, day)
Which year were you born in?: 1992
Which month were you born in?: 05
which day of the month were you born on?: 26
You age is: 25
Would you like to allow someone else to enter their age?(yes/no): yes
Please enter your birthday with this format(year, month, day)
Which year were you born in?: 2019
Which month were you born in?: 04
which day of the month were you born on?: 20
Be serious man
Enter your real age
Please enter your birthday with this format(year, month, day)
Which year were you born in?:
```

This is just some pseudo code, but the source of your issue could have been that you did not ensure that user input was in integer format. That is why We passed int before input in this code. In order for datetime.datetime to work with the date, you have to make it integer input, unless you use strptime() to parse string input, which I can also show you how to do. Next, it is better practice to use elif statements in your code rather than if statements if only one of the conditions can be True. Someone cannot be born on the same day and born on another day, so elif works better here rather than if. We also need to add a loop since someone could enter a value that is <= 0, which would be bogus, unless the 0 value is because they were born on this exact day, which is unlikely. We can handle that scenario with a continue statement in order to start the loop over again, and we can break out of the loop if the user enters a logical value and wants to stop entering birthdays.